# TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference. at naj_fla::MainTimeline/runMan()

Tags: actionscript-3, typeerror, movieclip, flash-cs6, timeline

I know that many people have asked the same question, but i tried everything to solve it and i don't know what else to do. 
I understand that this error appears when an objects is being called while that objects is not available in the timeline anymore. I tried putting the AS3 code in a separate layer, and since the object is available only in frame (1) I only put the action script code in frame (1) but it still shows the same error message when it reaches frame (2).

TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.  at naj_fla::MainTimeline/runMan()

```
stop();
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, runMan);

function runMan(e:Event):void {
    if (Loading_mc.currentFrame==Loading_mc.totalFrames) {
        gotoAndPlay(2);

    }
}
```

Comment: What is `Loading_mc`? Probably the scope of `Loading_mc` is outside the function `runMan`

Comment: @SakthiKumar Loading_mc is a movieclip that exists only in frame (1) and this code is in frame one only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your listener is still firing after you go to frame two, so try removing it first:

```
stop();
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, runMan);

function runMan(e:Event):void {
    if (Loading_mc.currentFrame==Loading_mc.totalFrames) {
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, runMan);
        gotoAndPlay(2);
    }
}
```